# gridview selected Item?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have 2 questions about Gridview:

1.I have enabled the selecting a row property in gridview, but I don't know how can I access the values of the row which has been selected?

2.as you see in my code I have a name parameter in my datasource and I want to value it with "session[search]"(for example) but I don't know how should I do it?

That is piece of my code:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [information] WHERE (CONTAINS([nam], @nam))" >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="nam"                   
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 3):

Question 1: Ans

Set the DataKeyNames of the grid view of the column name (say the ID from the DB which is in the Result set).

Now in the SelectedIndexChanged event handler writ the following code

```
 int selectedIndex = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
 string informationID= (GridView1.DataKeys[selectedIndex]["InformationID"]).ToString();
 gridview1.Rows[selectedIndex].cells("name").Text
```

Question 2:Ans

in datasource use sessionparameter for session

```
<SelectParameters>
   <asp:SessionParameter Name="nam" SessionField="select" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have enabled the selecting a row property in gridview, but I don't
>   know how can I access the values of the row which has been selected?

You can use [`GridView.SelectedRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow.aspx) property.

> Gets a reference to a GridViewRow object that represents the selected
>   row in the control.

Like `Gridview1.SelectedRow.Cells[0]`, `Gridview1.SelectedRow.Cells[1]` etc..

I don't understand your second question at all..

Comment: ok,thank you for your answer,can you say me where should I write these codes, in a new page or not in the current page ?for the second question,you see that I hav a "nam" placeholder in my select command,it doesn'n have any value and I want to assign it "session["x"](for example)" How can I do this?